# How do you retrieve an account to read state?

Tags: solana-program, rust

(Note: No Anchor solutions please, I'm trying to stick to raw Rust Solana dev for now using the solana-program crate)

After completing the [state management section in SolDev](https://soldev.app/course/program-state-management), I'm wondering how exactly one reads data from the network. Will the framework essentially plumb in data into the provided AccountInfo objects, in our `process_instruction` entry point?

Deriving a new PDA made enough sense because, I figured, I was actually creating the references to new memory... but a little lost on how to point to state that is already on-chain. Does this require a CPI against some provided program, like how I used the `create_account` system instruction?

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass the account to the program, you can't read from an account you didn't pass as an argument.

The VM will fetch all these accounts and provide them to your program.